# Play framework 2.4 form fill does not work

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

In Play Framework 2.4 Java, I need to fill a form using the following code, but it does not work. The output value of usereditform.field("email").value() is null. Anyone know why?

```
SignupClz signupobj = new SignupClz();
signupobj.email="abcd@efgh.com";
signupobj.name="abcd";
signupobj.password = "eoijf";

Form<SignupClz> usereditform = Form.form(SignupClz.class).fill(signupobj);
System.out.println(usereditform.field("email").value());
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is correct. Please look at other points - maybe you did not recognize "abcd@efgh.com" output in the console.

For example I have the similar code and it works:

```
EditForm rawEditForm = new EditForm();
rawEditForm.title = boxModel.title;
rawEditForm.body = boxModel.body;
rawEditForm.id = id;

Form<EditForm>  editForm = Form.form(EditForm.class).fill(rawEditForm);
Logger.info("Title: " + editForm.field("title").value());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am learning PlayFramework and stumbled upon this question.

For **PlayFramework 2.8** form field values cannot be directly accessed, be it reading or filling(writing) information.  You have to explicity tell it when building the form, like this :

```
 @Inject
 FormFactory formFactory;

 Form<SignupClz> usereditform = FormFactory.form(SignupClz.class) // 
                                .withDirectFieldAccess(true)
                                .fill(signupobj);

 System.out.println(usereditform.field("email").value());
```

Note that in this version forms are built using *FormFactory*, make sure you inject it or add it to your code otherwise.

Details in their official documentation [https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaForms#Defining-a-form:~:text=Instead%20of%20enabling%20%E2%80%9Cdirect%20field%20access%E2%80%9D%20for%20all%20forms%2C%20you%20can%20enable%20it%20only%20for%20specific%20ones%3A](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaForms#Defining-a-form:%7E:text=Instead%20of%20enabling%20%E2%80%9Cdirect%20field%20access%E2%80%9D%20for%20all%20forms%2C%20you%20can%20enable%20it%20only%20for%20specific%20ones%3A)